# String format function does not parse my slashes character?

Tags: python, wget

I am doing a small python script to perform a wget call, however I am encountering an issue when I am replacing the string that contains the url/ip address and that it will be given to my "wget" string

```
import os
import sys 

usr = sys.argv[1]
pswd = sys.argv[2]
ipAddr = sys.argv[3]

wget = "wget  http://{IPaddress}"
wget.format(IPaddress=ipAddr)
print "The command wget is %s" %wget

os.system(wget)
```

If I run that script I get the snippet below, wher I know that wget fails, because the variable ipAddr has not replaced IPaddress pattern, so I guess that the issue has to do with the slashes in the url. My question is why that pattern is not replaced?

```
python test.py 1 2  www.website.org  The command wget is wget  http://{IPaddress}

--2015-12-03 20:26:11--  http://%7Bipaddress%7D/

Resolving {ipaddress} ({ipaddress})... failed: Name or service not known.
```

Comment: Why are you using wget?

Comment: thanks @Rozuur, that is the solution!

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham, I use wget because I will need to do some calls to different websites where the url, after the ip address, will change and I would like to see the 200 OK output. Do you suggest another solution better than wget?

Comment: You can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't assigning the result of the `format` call to anything - you're just throwing it away. Try this instead:

```
wget = "wget  http://{IPaddress}"
wget = wget.format(IPaddress=ipAddr)
print "The command wget is %s" %wget

os.system(wget)
```

Alternatively, this seems a bit cleaner:

```
wget = "wget  http://{IPaddress}".format(IPaddress=ipAddr)
print "The command wget is %s" %wget

os.system(wget)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually format your `wget` string like this.

```
import os
import sys 

usr = sys.argv[1]
pswd = sys.argv[2]
ipAddr = sys.argv[3]

wget = "wget http://{IPaddress}".format(IPaddress=ipAddr)
print "The command wget is %s" % wget

os.system(wget)
```

`.format()` does not modify the string in place, it returns a copy of the modified string, so in your original script, the value of `wget.format(IPaddress=ipAddr)` is never actually assigned to any variable and the content of the `wget` variable remains unchanged